# Is it possible to convert between structs?

Tags: go, struct, mapping

Lets say I have the following two structs

```
type Struct1 struct {
   name string
   details interface{}
}

type AddressDetails struct {
   street string
}

type StructDetails struct {
   Struct1
   details AddressDetails
}
```

I get the input in JSON and I convert it into `Struct1`.  Now is it possible to convert this to `StructDetails` in golang without having to marshal and unmarshal again?  I tried this but I get an error

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: Conversion here is not possible, but assignment is: `var s1 Struct1; var sd StructDetails; sd.Struct1 = s1`.

Comment: Do you mean like a "cast"?

Answer (score 0):

You can write function to map `Struct1` to `StructDetails`

```
func ToStructDetails(s Struct1, d string) *StructDetails {
    return &StructDetails{s, AddressDetails{d}}
}
```

> Apart from doing a mapping, isn't there a way to force go to do the conversion.

Other way after unmarshalling

```
s := Struct1{"name", "details"}
var sd StructDetails
sd.Struct1 = s
fmt.Println(sd) // {{name details} {}}
sd.details = AddressDetails{"address"}
fmt.Println(sd) // {{name details} {address}}
```

Comment: Apart from doing a map, istn't there a way to force go to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the excellent [mapstructure](https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure) library which converts a `map[string]interface{}` into the struct you want. This way, you could just JSON decode your data into a map[string]interface{} and then decode this map into the structs you need.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure"
)

func main() {
    myJson := "{\"name\": \"someName\", \"age\": 20, \"job\": \"teacher\"}"
    myMap := make(map[string]interface{})

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(myJson), &myMap)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    person := &Person{}
    adult := &Adult{}

    err = mapstructure.Decode(myMap, person)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Person: %#v\n", person)

    err = mapstructure.Decode(myMap, adult)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Adult: %#v\n", adult)
}

// Structs

type Person struct {
    Name string `mapstructure:"name" json:"name"`
    Age int `mapstructure:"age" json:"age"`
}

type Adult struct {
    Person `mapstructure:",squash"`

    Job string `mapstructure:"job" json:"job"`
}
```

See it in action in [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/U-ubvutblFd).

Comment: I think this approach is unclear a bit -> `api` doesn't have strict contract between `json` and `struct`s

Comment: The question was how to convert from Struct1 to StructDetails without marshal and then unmarshal again. Obviusly it would be better to have a function to convert one type to another one explicitly, but if you want to do this automatically and without requiring to go to / from json again, and without having to write a lot of conversion functions, I think this is a nice way to do it in a few lines of code.

Comment: I think It's nice to add `myJson2 := "{ \"job\": \"teacher\"}"` example

Comment: I think that example would make sense only if the question was regarding data validation. In your json, some fields are missing. Using mapstructure or even json's Unmarshal function would have exactly the same result: Some fields in the struct would end with the zero values of their data types. After unmarshalling your data, you should validate it. You could even do it with a json schema also. But, again, the question was not about that. It was about how to convert between structs without using json, and I assumed a quick way was required since more explicit ways were already provided here.